# how to remove id with braces from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

My option looks like this:

```
<option value="80">a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 (80)</option>
```

With this code:

```
str_split = str.split(',');
```

i receive this:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 (80)
```

But i want to remove the id with the braces to get this:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
```

The id can vary like `"(8)"` or `"(20)"` or `"(100)"` and so on..

I tried it with

```
str_replace = str.replace(/[()]/g, "");
```

but it gives me this result:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 80
```

How do I do that?

**EDIT :**

is it possible to do this with the last braces with id from string?

just tested it and got problems when my option looks like this

```
<option value="80">a1(12), a2(test), a3(333), a4(xx), a5(34) (80)</option>
```

i want this

```
a1(12) a2(test) a3(333) a4(xx) a5(34)
```

Comment: You can use `strstr` like in PHP but you will need this function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015181/jquery-or-javascript-strstr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
var str_replace = str.replace(/\([^)]+\)$/,'')
```

How it works :

- `\(` : escaped opening parenthesis
- `[^)]` : not a closing parenthesis
- `+` : at least once
- `\)` : closing parenthesis, escaped
- `$` : end of string

Comment: If you want to remove it only at end of the string, use `str.replace(/\([^)]+\)$/,'')`. Is that your new question ? If you want to match only digits, use `str.replace(/\(\d+\)$/,'')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `.split()` and `.replace()` to do this:

1. **Using `.split()`:**

   ```
   var str_split = str.split(' (');
   var str_replace = str_split[0];
   ```
2. **Using `.replace()`:**

   ```
   var str_replace = str.replace(/ \([0-9]+\)/, "");
   ```

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wJP5x/)