# How to check if an element of an array is present in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I've already read a few questions here but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. Basically, I need to know if any of the elements present in an array are present in a string. An example:

```
var currentHref = "http://www.vorcu.com/hello";
var urls = [ 
    "vorcu.com",
    "neutronico.com",
    "word2.com"
       ];
```

So, I need to know if any of the elements in "urls" coincide with any of the text present in "currentHref". Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me introduce you to the [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery or JavaScript strstr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015181/jquery-or-javascript-strstr)

Comment: You're going to have to loop through the array. It might sound ugly, but I'd be surprised (happily) if there was another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone is providing the Javascript answer (which I fully support), but just because you mention jQuery I figure I'd provide an alternative:

```
var curHref = window.location.hostname.split('.'),
    // i imagine your static string was just for test purposes
    checkHref = curHref[1]+'.'+curHref[2],
    urls = [ 
        "vorcu.com",
        "neutronico.com",
        "word2.com"
    ];

if($.inArray(checkHref,urls) > -1){
    // its in there, do your magic
}
```

This creates the object I assume you wanted to check (hostname minus www) and if it matches any of the items in `urls` using the [jQuery inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array and use search:

```
str.search(arrItem)
```

will return the position of the match, or -1 if it isn't found.

Comment: indexOf is better unless you're using regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    if (currentHref.indexOf(urls[i]) != -1) {
        alert(urls[i]); // found occurence, break or continue
    }
}
```

Or RegExp way (above way is preferred):

```
var isInArray = RegExp(urls.join('|')).test(currentHref); // true|false
```

or

```
var matches = currentHref.match(urls.join('|')); // array of matches ["vorcu.com"]
```

Comment: don't forget to escape your regex... `new RegExp(urls.join('|').replace(/[\.\^$*+?()[{\\]/g,'\\$&'),'g').test(currentHref)`

Comment: @zamnuts one more reason why `for`-way is preferred :)

Answer (score 0):

A function like the following should work:

```
function containsAny(str, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (str.indexOf(arr[i]) !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternately you could use the slower but more terse:

```
RegExp(arr.join('|')).exec(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method, which is supported by many browsers:

```
var currentHref = "http://www.vorcu.com/hello";
var urls = [ 
    "vorcu.com",
    "neutronico.com",
    "word2.com"
       ];
var containsAny = urls.some(function(x) { return currentHref.indexOf(x) >= 0; });
```

For compatibility with browsers where `some` is not supported, the MDN article I've linked provides an implementation you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Make a foreach and then check indexOf ;)

Comment: There is no foreach in JavaScript.

Comment: @undefined technically yes, `Array.forEach`, although this isn't best for this use case