# PHP's strstr() equivalent for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I wrote this little piece of code for viewing the profile pictures that are set as private. But every time I have to access it, I have to turn Apache on on XAMPP. Also, it is pretty much useless on a computer that doesn't have Apache installed. So I wanted to write it in JavaScript but couldn't find an equivalent for `strstr()` function.

Could someone please let me know if there's an equivalent or alternative?

The code:

```
<?php
    //haystack
    $_POST['theaddress'] ='160x160/photo.jpg';

    //return all after the needle '160x160/', inclusive
    $varA = strstr($_POST['theaddress'], '160x160/');

   //build new URL
    $varA = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9"."$varA";

    header("Location: $varA");
?>
```

Comment: why you do not use `indexOf()`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: The first result google shows you is indexOf... You just need to type "javascript strstr"...

Comment: @Forlan07 Was expecting a more obvious function that splits the string rather than the one that returns the position. So.

Comment: I don't know why this question was voted down or marked as unclear. It's perfectly clear to anyone who understands both PHP and Javascript. @hindmost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript String's `indexOf()` function should meet all your requests

Next example does in JavaScript almost same what you wrote in PHP. Keep in mind that you need to be sure that you have a way to pass `$_POST['theaddress']` to your this function. (for example use PHP `setcookie()` function and then read value in JavaScript code

```
function reload(fileName) {
    // define server address variable
    var serverAddress = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9";

    // get the filename
    var fileName = fileName.indexOf("160x160/");

    // set new location based on server address and filename
    location.href = serverAddress + fileName;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danielvictorg/daog571x/
Pretty ugly code but it works. Used most of your code. Thanks!
Thought there would be a more obvious function than `indexOf()` as it returns the position of the string.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

```
function strstr(haystack, needle, bool) {
    // Finds first occurrence of a string within another
    //
    // version: 1103.1210
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/strstr    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // *     example 1: strstr(‘Kevin van Zonneveld’, ‘van’);
    // *     returns 1: ‘van Zonneveld’    // *     example 2: strstr(‘Kevin van Zonneveld’, ‘van’, true);
    // *     returns 2: ‘Kevin ‘
    // *     example 3: strstr(‘name@example.com’, ‘@’);
    // *     returns 3: ‘@example.com’
    // *     example 4: strstr(‘name@example.com’, ‘@’, true);    // *     returns 4: ‘name’
    var pos = 0;

    haystack += "";
    pos = haystack.indexOf(needle); if (pos == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (bool) {
            return haystack.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
            return haystack.slice(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://phpjs.org/functions/strstr/

Comment: Your actual source is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015181/jquery-or-javascript-strstr, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @Forlan07 No, my source is the first result with google using "strstr js"

Comment: no need for elses after returns

Answer (score 2):

```
var string='aadsasdsad160x160/saddas'
    console.log(string.indexOf('160x160/'))
```

this will output 10

Answer (score 1):

As usual a solution is already provided when I get back..

```
function strstr(haystack, needle, before_needle) {
    if(haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0) 
        return before_needle ? haystack.substr(0, haystack.indexOf(needle)) 
               : haystack.substr(haystack.indexOf(needle));
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String.prototype.strstr = function(search) {
    var position = this.indexOf(search);
    if (position == -1) {
        // not found
        return false;
    }

    return this.slice(position);
};

var x = 'Hello cruel world';
alert(x.strstr('cruel'));
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/bsr3jcuw/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
function strstr(haystack, needle, bool) {  

    var pos = 0;

    haystack += '';
    pos = haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf((needle + '').toLowerCase());
    if (pos == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (bool) {
            return haystack.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
            return haystack.slice(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example1:**

stristr('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'Van');

returns: 'van Zonneveld'.

**Example2:**

stristr('Kevin van Zonneveld', 'VAN', true);

returns: 'Kevin '

Reference: http://phpjs.org/functions/stristr/